# Sorting bar chart

Tags: python-3.x, bar-chart, data-analysis

I am using [Car dataset from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/ljanjughazyan/cars1) for data analysis.

I am going to build a bar chart using Overall_MPG against Make. The Overall_MPG is derived from the code below:

```
overall_mpg = sorted_group_df['MPG_City'] - sorted_group_df['MPG_Highway']

print(overall_mpg)
```

Then I rename the newly added column from the overall_mpg as Overall_mpg

```
combined_sorted_group_df = pd.concat([sorted_group_df, overall_mpg.rename('Overall_mpg')], axis=1)

combined_sorted_group_df.head()
```

Then I build a bar chart with the code below:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,10))

plt.bar(combined_sorted_group_df['Make'], combined_sorted_group_df['Overall_mpg'], data=combined_sorted_group_df)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.xlabel('Brand')
plt.ylabel('Overall_mpg')
plt.title('Overal MPG of Car')
```

Here is the bar chart:
[image: Original bar chart]

In order to sort the var chart in ascending order, I add .sort_values() into the code

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,10))

plt.bar(combined_sorted_group_df['Make'], combined_sorted_group_df['Overall_mpg'].sort_values(), data=combined_sorted_group_df)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.xlabel('Brand')
plt.ylabel('Overall_mpg')
plt.title('Overal MPG of Car')
```

Here is the bar chart
[image: Sorted bar chart]

The problem is that the value for each car brand (Make) is different between the original bar chart and sorted bar chart.

Anyone can enlighten me when is the problem?

Comment: The problem would be that you are sorting one column that doesn't sort the other columns, what you need is sth like `sort_values(by=['Overall_mpg'], inplace=true)` before calling the bar

Comment: @M.Abdeldayem, adding variable to the sort_values() will result error message and no bar chart.

If I separate out the sort_values():
bb = combined_sorted_group_df['Overall_mpg'].sort_values('Overall_mpg', axis=0, inplace=True)

plt.bar(combined_sorted_group_df['Make'], bb, data=combined_sorted_group_df)

The error message is "TypeError: sort_values() got multiple values for argument 'axis'"

If  I remove the axis, the error message would be ": No axis named Overall_mpg for object type Series"

Comment: @M.Abdeldayem, 
Besides, I want to rank the bar on the x-axis (the Make variable) in either ascending or descending, the feature for the by should be Overall_mpg or Make? I should be using axis=1 since I would rank the feature which is in column, am I right?